# How do I remove all traces of SVN from my directory?

Tags: linux, svn, unix

I want it to be cleared of SVN, recursively, but of course keep my files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean killing all the .svn directories? This should do it:

```
find -name '.svn' -type d -exec rm -rf {} ';'
```

EDIT: Updated from comments. Doh!

Comment: It keeps saying: rmdir: failed to remove `./mobileapps/.svn': Directory not empty

Comment: @timex: it should be `find ./ -name ".svn" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: @TIMEX: replace `rmdir` with `rm -rf`

Comment: @TIMEX Sorry about that. My brain was elsewhere. Definitely should have been rm -rf instead of rmdir.

Answer (score 2):

use find and look for the .svn directories

find . -name "FILE-TO-FIND"-exec rm -rf {} \;

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch a new copy from the svn repository using the `svn export` command instead of `svn checkout`. The resulting tree will have no SVN bits in it.